# How can I manually add an item to GridView.Items after binding ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-8, .net-4.5

I currently have a GridView populated with ItemsSource binding to an ObservableCollection.

It's showing the items as I intended but I'd like to manually add one more item at the end that looks and behaves differently. Is there a way I can do it without modifying the ObservableCollection the ItemsSource is bound to?

Comment: When you say look and behaves diffently what do you mean more precisely? another `DataTemplate`

Comment: Basically the grid will contain a bunch of images and there's a last grid item saying 'View all'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this:

1. Using MVVM the original collection would be pulled up from the model layer and the additional item would be added in the view-model. It works as you can consider the additional item required *only* for the view, e.g. for example a list of poll options where you need to add an 'all of the above'.
2. Have two collections, separate, and then concatenate/join them together using an `IValueConverter` when you bind the `ItemsSource`. This approach is more tricky and only really useful when you need both collections separate and combined, e.g. a list of items in one collection and a list of item categories in another but also combined.

I have successfully used both approaches in a large widely-used WPF application.

**Edit:** Reading the comment on the question, if you did mean that you want a different visual or behaviour of the additional item you can achieve that using an Selector `DataTemplateSelector` and/or `ItemContainerStyleSelector`. I recently used a combination of option #2 and template selecting successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

Use a CompositeCollection, you can define this is xaml. Not sure if it would solve the issue, you might need to play around with it a bit

Create a new collection behind the scenes that is populated with the items from your collection + the extra item.

Write a converter than creates a new collection (or returns an IEnumerable) with the new item added.

I guess all of these options have a common theme in that they are all a new collection. You basically can't bind directly to the original collection because it doesn't have the extra item, so you have to bind to something else in some form.